# Extract generic type into interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have two Interfaces

```
  public interface IEventBusExchange<in TQueue, TMessage> 
    where TQueue : struct
    where TMessage : DtoBase
  {
    Task PublishAsync(TMessage message);
    Task SubscribeAsync(TQueue queue, Func<TMessage, bool> callback);
  }
```

```
  public interface ISubscriber<TQueue, TMessage> : ISubscriber
    where TQueue : struct
    where TMessage : class
  {
    TQueue Queue { get; }
    Task<bool> CallbackAsync(TMessage message);
  }
```

and an Abstract class of ISubscribe

```
  public abstract class Subscriber<TExchange, TQueue, TMessage> : ISubscriber<TQueue, TMessage> 
    where TExchange : IEventBusExchange<TQueue, TMessage>
    where TQueue : struct
    where TMessage : DtoBase
  {
    ...
  }
```

What i want to do, is extract TQueue and TMessage from IEventbusExchange so i can make the abstract class more simple and type safe.

Is it possible to do this in c#?

The solution should look like this:

```
  public abstract class Subscriber<TExchange> : ISubscriber<TQueue, TMessage>   
    where TExchange : IEventBusExchange<TQueue, TMessage>
  {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Every type parameter you want to use in the class has to be explicitly declared, and there's no type constraint inference. What you already have is as simple as it can be made.

Comment: No, you need to constrain the components to match the `IEventBusExchange`'s requirements.

Comment: Then i will leave it as it is. Thannk you